# How can I correlate SQL Server performance metrics to the stored procedures that are causing problems

Tags: sql-server, performance

the situation is that there are certain stored procedures and/or ad-hoc SQL that is causing our CPU to spike from 30 to 80% and dropping all our indexes out of memory, I'm wondering if there is a well established way to correlate the performance spikes (CPU, Disk Read, etc.) to particular instances of SP running..

Comment: Is it SOF etiquette to accept answers?  I'm assuming so from your comment.

Comment: Here's how it works: you ask questions, we give answers. You are rewarded by getting an answer, and sometimes by getting points for asking a good question. We are rewarded by earning points from the votes on our answers. You are supposed to select/accept the best answer, which gives us even more points. And by indicating the best answer, you help others who find your question in their own search for help. When you don't "accept" a best answer, you benefit from getting an answer, but the people doing the answering don't get credit, and are therefore reluctant to keep answering your questions.

Comment: What if:
a:  there are 2 or 3 equally good answers
b:  there are no good answers

Comment: @Tom - If there are no good answers don't feel compelled to accept one. If there are equally good ones just pick one! Toss a coin, choose the one posted first, the one with the lowest rep. Whatever!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Performance Monitor.**  If Sql Server 2008 --> *Start, Program Files, Microsoft Sql Server 2008, Performance Tools, Sql Server Profiler*.  **Produces a trace.**  Trace contains all sorts of information.  For instance, with a bit of work, one could find the begin and end trace events of a stored procedure, note that the time that it was running covered the spikes, then further verify by looking @ the resource counters collected by the trace.  Try this link over at sql server performance: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/correlate_trace_performance_p1.aspx
- Use Alerts in SQL Server Agent to fire off custom T-SQL which captures what is running @ that particular time.  Sql Server Agent, Alerts, General, new alert, Type = SQL Server Performance condition alert ( setup as you wish ), Response, Execute job.  The job has a sql script which writes to a table - telling you what was happening.  All sorts of worlds could be your oyster.  For instance, you could ask yourself - hey, what clr is in memory right now?

What's in memory right now?

```
SELECT
  a.*
 ,cla.*
 ,clr_ad.*
 ,state_desc = CASE clr_ad.[state]
     WHEN N'E_APPDOMAIN_CREATING' THEN 'The AppDomain is being created.'
     WHEN N'E_APPDOMAIN_SHARED' THEN 'The runtime AppDomain is ready for use by multiple users.'
     WHEN N'E_APPDOMAIN_SINGLEUSER' THEN 'The AppDomain is ready for use in DDL operations. These differ from E_APPDOMAIN_SHARED in that shared AppDomains are used for CLR integration executions as opposed to DDL operations. Such AppDomains are isolated from other concurrent operations.'
     WHEN N'E_APPDOMAIN_DOOMED' THEN 'The AppDomain is scheduled to be unloaded, but there are currently threads executing in it.'
     WHEN N'E_APPDOMAIN_UNLOADING' THEN 'SQL Server has requested that the CLR unload the AppDomain, usually because the assembly that contains the managed database objects has been altered or dropped.'
     WHEN N'E_APPDOMAIN_UNLOADED' THEN 'The CLR has unloaded the AppDomain. This is usually the result of an escalation procedure due to ThreadAbort, OutOfMemory, or an unhandled exception in user code.'
     WHEN N'E_APPDOMAIN_ENQUEUE_DESTROY' THEN 'The AppDomain has been unloaded in CLR and set to be destroyed by SQL Server.'
     WHEN N'E_APPDOMAIN_DESTROY' THEN 'The AppDomain is in the process of being destroyed by SQL Server.'
     WHEN N'E_APPDOMAIN_ZOMBIE' THEN 'The AppDomain has been destroyed by SQL Server; however, not all of the references to the AppDomain have been cleaned up.'
     ELSE '?'
     END
FROM
  sys.dm_clr_loaded_assemblies cla
  JOIN sys.assemblies a
    ON cla.assembly_id = a.assembly_id
  JOIN sys.dm_clr_appdomains clr_ad
    ON cla.appdomain_address = clr_ad.appdomain_address
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 indirect ways that I can think of

- Note CPU, Read, Writes via profiler of a stored proc call
  We've used this recently to spot expensive IO/CPU compared to duration
- Use DMVs to find most expensive on our system, this shows stored procs too

Example:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    QS.total_logical_reads,
    QS.total_logical_writes, 
    QS.execution_count,
    QS.total_logical_reads + QS.total_logical_writes AS [IO_total],
    QS.total_logical_reads / QS.execution_count AS Avg_Reads_per_Execution,
    ST.[text] AS query_text,
    db_name(ST.dbid) AS database_name,
    ST.objectid AS OBJECT_ID
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats  QS
    CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) ST
WHERE 
    QS.total_logical_reads + QS.total_logical_writes > 0 
    --AND ST.dbid IS NULL 
ORDER BY 
    [IO_total] DESC;
```